# 404 error returned from WebClient.DownloadFile request

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm having difficulties downloading a product image from tkmaxx.com

http://www.tkmaxx.com/content/ebiz/tkmaxx/invt/B./1./A./21866003/21866003_medium.jpg

```
try
{
    string filePath = "D:\\temp\\test.jpg";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.tkmaxx.com/content/ebiz/tkmaxx/invt/B./1./A./21866003/21866003_medium.jpg", filePath);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

I keep receiving a 404 error message. I have taken a look at a lot of forum threads, however I cannot seem to resolve this issue.

The only thing that i can think of is that TXMAXX.com have some server settings that does not allow image download?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   string url = "http://framework.zend.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.11.11/ZendFramework-1.11.11.zip";
   WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
   downloader.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadFileCompleted);
   downloader.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(downloader_DownloadProgressChanged);
   downloader.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), "C:\\temp.zip");
  }

 void downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
   {
      label1.Text = e.BytesReceived + " " + e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
  void downloader_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Error != null)
         MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
       else
         MessageBox.Show("Completed!!!");
   }
```

Ref: [Downloaded file using webclient.DownloadFileAsync has 0KB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373368/downloaded-file-using-webclient-downloadfileasync-has-0kb)

Comment: I have tried this code, however I receive the same problem. THis time I get a MessageBox displaying the error

Comment: Hi @user2008865: 
i tried same with 
                                                           

string filePath = "D:\\test.jpg";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.google.com/logos/2013/dia_dos_namorados_2013-1529005-hp.jpg", filePath);

its working fine for me.

Please check your destination filepath is corect and also check the url is having the image or not.

Comment: The google logo downloads ok, its this image that will not work at all. Could you give it a go your end for me? http://www.tkmaxx.com/content/ebiz/tkmaxx/invt/B./1./A./21866003/21866003_medium.jpg