# Wait until file is downloaded from URL via webClient

Tags: c#, webclient

I have struggle with downloading few MB excel file from URL and then work with it. Im using VS2010 so i cant use await keyword.
My code follows:

```
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    // setting Windows Authentication
                    webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    // event fired ExcelToCsv after file is downloaded
                    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (sender, e) => ExcelToCsv(fileName);
                    // start download
                    webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://serverx/something/Export.ashx"), exportPath);
                }
```

The line in `ExcelToCsv()` method

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
```

Throws me an error:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process.

I tried `webClient.DownloadFile()` only without an event but it throws same error. Same error is throwed if i do not dispose too. What can i do ?

Temporary workaround may be `Sleep()` method but its not bullet proof.

Thank you

EDIT:
I tried second approach with standard handling but i have mistake in the code

```
  using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    // nastaveni ze webClient ma pouzit Windows Authentication
                    webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                    // <--- I HAVE CONVERT ASYNC ERROR IN THIS LINE
                    webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(HandleDownloadDataCompleted);

                    // spusteni stahovani
                    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://czprga2001/Logio_ZelenyKyblik/Export.ashx"), TempDirectory + PSFileName);
                }

public delegate void DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(string fileName);
        public event DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler DownloadDataCompleted;
        static void HandleDownloadDataCompleted(string fileName)
        { 
            ExcelToCsv(fileName);
        }
```

EDIT: approach 3
I tried this code

```
while (true)
                {
                    if (isFileLocked(downloadedFile))
                    {
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //wait 5s
                        ExcelToCsv(fileName);
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

and it seems that it is never accessible :/ I dont get it.

Comment: You may have a lock on the file you're trying to create from a previous failed run of your code. Also, make sure you don't have the file you're trying to create/overwrite open in any other applications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to check if a file is in use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use)

Comment: Cory: i delete downloaded file before download. Prix: i dont need to check if file is accessible, i need to wait until download is completed. but i will try while on that function but its not elegant way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8373461/2224701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `DownloadFile` instead of `DownloadFileAsync`, as you do in Edit 1, like this:

```
string filename=Path.Combine(TempDirectory, PSFileName);
using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    // nastaveni ze webClient ma pouzit Windows Authentication
                    webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;    
                    // spusteni stahovani
                    webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://czprga2001/Logio_ZelenyKyblik/Export.ashx"), filename);
                }
ExcelToCsv(filename);  //No need to create the event handler if it is not async
```

From your example it seems that you do not need asynchronous download, so use synchronous download and avoid possible related problems like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8373368/2224701).

Also use `Path.Combine` to combine parts of a path like folder and filename.

There is also a chance that it is locked by something else, use Sysinternals Process Explorer's Find DLL or Handle function to check it.

Use local disk to store downloaded file to prevent problems with network.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but it throws me same error about file is used.

Comment: Is there a chance that you are downloading it twice on multiple threads or something like this?

Comment: Also Sysinternals Process Explorer has a Find handle function that shows which process really locks the file.

Comment: I found that the problem is related to the fact that download directory is network disk, on local disk it works like a charm, thanks :-)